# ArrayList to DavidWebb Android

Tags: java, android, post, arraylist, httpurlconnection

I am using [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb) for making Http POST requests. I have ArrayList or HashMap for all the params that I want to send. How can I pass an array of params using DavidWebb?

Right now I am doing this like

```
Response<String> resp = webb
                    .post(Constants.URL + Constants.CUSTOMER_SIGNUP)
                    .param("username", params.get("username"))
                    .param("user_contact_no", params.get("user_contact_no"))
```

I want to do something like

```
Response<String> resp = webb
                        .post(Constants.URL + Constants.CUSTOMER_SIGNUP)
                        .arraylist/hasmap of params
```

Comment: How do you get key/value pairs from an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I want to use one method to send the request for my whole app. No matter which params am I sending. I am passing the HashMap of all the params. So I just want to send the hashmap as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. "Andy Turner"'s answer clicked.

```
Request request = webb
                    .post(Constants.URL + Constants.CUSTOMER_SIGNUP);
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                        request.param(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
            Response<String> resp = request.readTimeout(30000)
                    .connectTimeout(30000)
                    .asString();
```

Comment: I've added an issue to address this requirement: https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/issues/13

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with the specific library, you can just iterate the entry set of `params` if it is a `HashMap`:

```
Response<String> resp = webb
                .post(Constants.URL + Constants.CUSTOMER_SIGNUP);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
  resp = resp.param(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Your answer needed modifications but thanks for the answer. It helped me in finding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.2.0 (released 2015-11-12) you can do it this way:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("string", "a string can contain &");
params.put("number", 4711);
params.put("null", null);
params.put("empty", "");

Response<String> response = webb
        .post("/my-url")
        .params(params)
        .asString();
```